# how to get the result of the select query and pass it as a input to delete query in Function Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(name VARCHAR (255))

RETURNS INTEGER AS

$BODY$

DECLARE

emp_id INTEGER;

BEGIN
 SELECT employee.employee_id into emp_id from employee where first_name = name;
 
 DELETE FROM employee WHERE employee_id = emp_id;

 return emp_id;

END

$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

when i call the function its deleting all the records in my employee table.

Comment: Why don't you just do `DELETE FROM employee WHERE first_name = name RETURNING employee_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First store value in a variable for given input and these execute delete command with this variable and return this variable.

```
-- PostgreSQL
-- create table and store data
create table employee (emp_id int, name varchar(255));
insert into employee values (1, 'Rahul'), (2, 'Biswas'), (3, 'Shuva');

-- create function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(p_name varchar(255))

RETURNS INTEGER AS

$BODY$

DECLARE v_emp_id INTEGER;

BEGIN
 SELECT e.emp_id into v_emp_id from employee e where e.name = p_name;
 
 DELETE FROM employee WHERE emp_id = v_emp_id;

 return v_emp_id;

END

$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- execute function
select * from test('Rahul');
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4c134787dafd8fe58b032d700168318d